# Count of grep across tables?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a table with a single column:

**Varieties**

```
Cara Cara  
Mandarin  
Seville  
Juice Orange  
Tangerine  
(... 100+ varieties)
```

And I have a table, in which one column lists varieties grown at each orchard separated by comma:

**Orchard Name** | **City Name** | **State Name** | **Varieties grown**

```
Orchard 1 | City | State | Cara Cara, Mandarin, Juice, Tangerine  
Orchard 2 | City | State | Cara Cara  
Orchard 3 | City | State | Seville  
(... 1,000+ orchards)
```

What's the most efficient way to create a new table with a summarized count of the number of orchards growing each variety:

**Orchard** | **Count**

```
Cara Cara | 521  
Seville | 470
```

(and so on, for each of the 100+ varieties)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a larger sample of data? You can paste the output of `dput`

Comment: Ideally you would have the table in a long format where each row is an individual variety at an orchard, then you can do a dplyr summarize group by variety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` to split `Varieties.grown` into multiple rows, then right join with `varieties` table to obtain only `Varieties` we're interested. Finally, `group_by(Varieties.grown)` and count all the non-NA `Orchard.Name` to get `Count` by `Varieties`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Varieties.grown, sep = "\\s?,\\s?") %>%
  right_join(varieties, by = c("Varieties.grown"="Varieties")) %>%
  group_by(Varieties.grown) %>%
  summarize(Count = sum(!is.na(Orchard.Name))) %>%
  rename(Varieties = Varieties.grown)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     Varieties Count
         <chr> <int>
1    Cara Cara     2
2 Juice Orange     0
3     Mandarin     1
4      Seville     1
5    Tangerine     1
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Orchard.Name = c("Orchard 1", "Orchard 2", "Orchard 3"
), City.Name = c("City", "City", "City"), State.Name = c("State", 
"State", "State"), Varieties.grown = c("Cara Cara, Mandarin, Juice, Tangerine", 
"Cara Cara", "Seville")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Orchard.Name", 
"City.Name", "State.Name", "Varieties.grown"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

varieties = structure(list(Varieties = c("Cara Cara", "Mandarin", "Seville", 
"Juice Orange", "Tangerine")), .Names = "Varieties", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- this is useful, but perhaps my question was very slightly different.  In this case, you're basing everything off of Varieties.grown.  Is it possible to base the summary/count off of the other Varieties table?  Hypothetically, I could have varieties that aren't grown in any orchard.  Granted, I could join the table you created back to the stand-alone Varieties table - I was just curious if matching across tables was possible.

Comment: @invisible_inq So for the case of `Varieties` not grown in any orchard, would you have a count for zero?

Comment: Ideally, yes.  If in 'Varieties' there was an entry for 'Golden Delicious', the count would be zero.